# Product of vectors

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, vectors, linear-transformations

[Textbook example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0BeM9.jpg)

I'm not sure if this is an error in my textbook, but isn't PQ supposed to be (1,-2.0)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, it looks like it's $-2$.

Answer (score -1):

Yes, good eye.

The textbook has defined the vector **PQ**=<(2-1),(0-2),(1-1)> which evaluates to **PQ**=<1, -2, 0>.